# .htaccess domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have a server which has 3 domains all pointing to it. All domains are on the same website.

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
```

How can I redirect www.domain3.com to www.domain3.com/test.html using .htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all three domains sharing the same website? or are they on different sites?

Comment: yes there are on the same website. I'm using wordpress mu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your .htaccess, put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.domain3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain3.com/test.html [R=301,NC]
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `domain3`'s .htaccess, put:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.domain2.com/test.html
```

Comment: thanks for this. but I got the my question wrong. Please see edited version. thanks!