# i have created a .htaccess file and want to be able two redirect users to another directory on the server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have two domains on pointing to the same IP
i have created a .htaccess file and want to be able two redirect users to another directory on the server if thay get to 
the website from a specific URL something like this:

if(url==www.abc.com || url==abc.com)
   redirect -www.othersite.com

thanks

Comment: An effective duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374330/htaccess-domain-redirect

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](http://dmr.ath.cx/notes/rewrite.html) you can write something like that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.png http://www.somewhere.com/something.gif [R]
```

Comment: Ok, to help giving you the best answer please share what you have already tried, thanks

Comment: yes you are right i have tried this also

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/ [L,R=301]

but nothing happens get error 500