# Redirect index.html to index.html#2

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering if it's possible to make a redirect if the user types:

www.arturhaddad.com
automatically going to
www.arturhaddad.com/index.html#2

Tried the cpanel redirect function but it redirects me to http://www.arturhaddad.com/index.html%232

Any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374330/htaccess-domain-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can include it as a redirect. Use the `NE` flag to keep it from encoding it. Put this in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?arturhaddad\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.arturhaddad.com/index.html#2 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing it or user another browser to check.

Comment: Great job, how do i set it to arturhaddad.com too (it's working only for www.arturhaddad.com now)?

Comment: @ArturHaddad Ok see the update so it will match both.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly that will be maked over javascript.
check over Javascript the **location.hash** variable and if that dont exists, you can make an redirect or a pushState to add these on the URL.

You can only make a redirect on servers side. You have no access (only over javascript) to check the location hash.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your index.html and it will redirect you to where you wanna go.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=LINK HERE" />
```